# Youtube iframe API - resetting volume

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I created an embedded iframe with the api and set the volume to zero. I use a script to change the source of the iframe, and noticed that the volume goes back to full.

I tried attaching `player.setVolume(0);` to the script to execute each time the source of the iframe is changed, but I'm getting an error that endlessly repeats a few times per second, constantly:

`Unable to post message to http://www.youtube.com. Recipient has origin https://www.youtube.com.
 www-widgetapi-vflXx2oJO.js:26
g.A www-widgetapi-vflXx2oJO.js:26
g.F www-widgetapi-vflXx2oJO.js:25`

this is the exact script:

```
$("#channel-1").click(function(){

$("#tv").attr("src", channel1);
$(".mid-bar").text("TNT");
player.setVolume(0);

});
```

where #tv is the iframe element generated by the youtube iframe api.

**What's a better way to change the video source while keeping the volume at 0?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$("#tv").attr("src", channel1);
```

Try

```
player.cueVideoById(channel1);
```

(or `player.loadVideoById` if you want it to autoplay)

That should load a new video into the existing player, keeping all other player parameters the same (including any event listeners you've set up).